# How to print from index location of a string from list containing index locations

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a loop that will search a string for a specific word that appears multiple times then print the next 12 characters that appear after that.

I have found the index location of each repeating word using the code below.

```
a = [m.start() for m in re.finditer("username", str(Searchable_String))]
print("index Locations:", a)
```

Which gives me the output in a list like below.

```
index Locations: [61, 216, 371, 526, 681, 836]
```

Now I am trying to print the string from each index location in the list but cannot figure this out.

I new to python and I'm completely stuck at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in a:
   print(your_string_var[i:i+12])
```

How it works:

```
string = "my explanation"

>>> print(string[0:2])
my
>>> print(string[0:1])
m
>>> print(string[0:2])
my
>>> print(string[2:])
 explanation
```

In practice you can slice a string  using this templates :

`string[start:end]`

or

`string[start:end:step]` : Get all characters from start to end-1 discounting every step character

So  if you have start positions in a list , and you want print 12 characters after every position  you can loop  your list of position, use position as start of the slice  and  position + 12  as the end of the slice.

Comment: An explanation of how the code posted works would help OP

Comment: This worked fantastically. Much better than my previous method of repeating code!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware, what you are actually creating is a python list, and lists have indexes

So you can write a code like this one:

```
for index in a:
    print(Searchable_String[index:])
```

which will find the index of that character and print the rest of the string from that point on.

If you want you can also specify an end-point for your string slicing.

The term

```
Searchable_String[index:]
```

means start from index eg = 61 and print everything onward.